# How to Force Click on All "Like" Links on Facebook.com via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

If I'm on http://facebook.com and I use Firebug or some other console to run some JavaScript on the site directly... is it possible to force the links to trigger their appropriate `POST`s to https://www.facebook.com/ajax/ufi/like.php? I have tried the following quick and dirty method:

```js
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
s.type = "text/javascript";

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);

$(".UFILikeLink").click();
```

... but, of course, it doesn't work. I am wondering what method I might take with plain JS or otherwise to force that event. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't make anything predefined happen, only anything you specify, such as a new `function(e){console.debug(e); return something;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
s.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(s)
console.log($)
s.onreadystatechange = function() {console.log($)};
s.onload = function() { console.log($)};
```

Notice that the console.log($) throws an undefined, I think jQuery was not loaded at the time you added invoke the $().click().

So you wait for the Script to load and be ready.
    s.onreadystatechange = function() {console.log($)};
    s.onload = function() { console.log($)};

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because $(".UFILikeLink") returns a list (assuming jQuery is loaded). You may need to call click on each individual element (like button)

Working solution:

```
$(".UFILikeLink[title^='Like this']").each( function (index) { this.click(); });
```

It is good to add some delay (say 5sec) before clicking and change its color such that we recognize it ;) also keep it in view.

```
$(".UFILikeLink[title^='Like this']").each( function (i) { 
    setTimeout(function(e) { 
        e.style.color = '#FF0000'; 
        e.click(); 
        e.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(); 
    }.bind(null, this), i*5000); 
});
```

Enjoy!